# How to print data from a GridView in Crystal Reports using Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, crystal-reports

I have a DataGridView populated using index numbers of Rows and Columns (No Dataset or DataSource)

e.g:

```
 dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "ABC";
 dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "XYZ";
```

Now I want it to be printed on Crystal Report. How do I provide dataSource to Crystal Report or simply how can I achieve it?

As well as data from GridView, I also need to print some other data from textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this kind of application.

First, I export to XML the datasource of the datagridview
Second, I used this XML  as the source for the crystal reports.

```
 void TransferDataToReport()
    {
         DataTable dT = GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1);
                dSet.Tables.Add(dT);
                try
                {
                    dSet.AcceptChanges();
          dSet.WriteXml(@"C:\Data.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
      }
      catch (FileLoadException) { }

     ReportDocument cr = new ReportDocument();
                string filePath = @"C:\CrystalReportData.rpt";
                cr.Load(filePath);
                cr.SetDataSource(dSet);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
    }

 public DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.ValueType);
        }

        object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```